# How to access items by "group" in an Outlook VB macro?

Tags: vba, outlook

By "group" I mean the collapsible classifications that you get when you enable View->Arrange By->Show in Groups.  This divides e.g. messages in a folder into Today, Yesterday, Last Week, Two Weeks Ago, and so on.  What I'd like to be able to do is iterate over the messages that are currently classified within a given group.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specfic group you want i.e just today etc. if so if you can recreate the query and search.

example here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147594.aspx